# Grails include warnings in test report

Tags: grails, testing, test-reporting

When i run `grails test-app` i get some warnings. I want those warnings to be included in the final test report! SO that i can analyse what is wrong better.

I tried to use the `-echoOut` flag but the warnings are not being treated as a standard output! I did not find any documentation for the command line args.

Is there any command line flag that i could set so that there reports could also include warnings? Is there any way at all to get the warnings in a file along side which test caused the warning?

### EDIT

I run my tests in IntelliJ IDEA and i noticed when i export the test results, IDEA also included the warnings in the report. How do i achieve that from the command line? I can't find the args IDEA uses.